# SQLAlchemy: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a form that allows a user to send a picture, a title and a description and to save these in an SQLAlchemy database but I get an error:

this is my app.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import bcrypt
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, fields,TextField, StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField,validators
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length, DataRequired
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

########################### CONFIG
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(32)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
app.config['USE_SESSION_FOR_NEXT'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

...

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    picture = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)


@app.route('/newproject', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def newproject():
    form = Project()
    if request.method == "POST":
        req = request.form
        title = req["title"]
        description = req["description"]
        print(req)
        if request.files:
            if allowed_image_filesize(request.cookies.get("filesize")):
                print("ERROR: File exceeded maximum size")
                return redirect(request.url)
            print(request.cookies)
            image = request.files["image"]
            if image.filename=="":
                print("ERROR: Image must have a name")
                return redirect(request.url)
            if not allowed_image(image.filename):
                print("ERROR: That image extension is not allowed")
                return redirect(request.url)
            else:
                filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], filename))
            print(image)
            project = Project(title=title, picture="static/img/uploads/"+filename, description=description)
            db.session.add(project)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('newproject.html', form = form)
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with my form:

```
<form class="newProjectForm" action="/newproject" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="newProjectFormBox">
    <div class="newProjectLabel">
      <label class="projectTitle">Select image</label>
    </div>
    <div class="newProjectSubFormBox">
          <label for="image" class="newProjectItemLine"> Select image: </label>
        <div>
          <input oninput="filesize(this);" type="file" class="newProjectItemLine" name="image" id="image"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newProjectLabel">
      <label class="projectTitle">Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="newProjectSubFormBox">
        <div>
          <label for="text" class="newProjectItemLine"> Write description and title: </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label class="projectTitle">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label class="projectTitle">Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="description" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="cvBoxDownload" type="submit">
    Post new project
  </button>
</form>
```

On the online page I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table project has no column named picture
[SQL: INSERT INTO project (title, picture, description, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('TitleTest', 'static/img/uploads/polytechnique.jpg', 'DescriptionTest', '2020-05-10 01:55:06.010419')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

in the terminal I get:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('title', 'TitleTest'), ('description', 'DescriptionTest')])
ImmutableMultiDict([('Pycharm-75942949', 'e31fe837-6d5d-4622-92bb-2a3cb57d9005'), ('session', 'eyJfZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiNjNlZGU0MTM1Zjk4MzI5NGNhYTY1YzYzZDNlMDRjYmJiZmFlMjcwYyJ9.XreXJQ.yR0PMpXYZcXhv0GWz6SpmWcEkPM'), ('filesize', '26873')])
<FileStorage: 'polytechnique.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 01:55:06] "POST /newproject HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table project has no column named picture

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/hugo/Desktop/website/app.py", line 91, in newproject
    db.session.commit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2479, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2617, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2577, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1137, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table project has no column named picture
[SQL: INSERT INTO project (title, picture, description, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('TitleTest', 'static/img/uploads/polytechnique.jpg', 'DescriptionTest', '2020-05-10 01:55:06.010419')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Do you have any idea where the error might be coming from ?

Comment: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table project has no column named picture` - do you need to re-create your model?

Comment: If you add a new column attribute to your ORM model you need to either recreate the database or perform a migration that adds the new column to the underlying table.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I recreated the database and it worked !